# html form to insert in mysql with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to have `form` which insert data into `mysql` db.

CODE - `index.php`

```
<form action="index3.php" method="POST"/>

    Kunde: <input type="text" name"Kunde">
    <br/>
    Produkt: <input type="text" name"Produkt">
    <br/>
    Produktversion: <input type="text" name"Produktversion">
    <br/>
    Menge: <input type="text" name"Menge">

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value"Insert">
</form>
```

CODE - `index3.php`

```
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $value1 = $_POST['Kunde'];
    $value2 = $_POST['Produkt'];
    $value3 = $_POST['Produktversion'];
    $value4 = $_POST['Menge'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Aufträge` (`id`, `Datum`, `Kunde`, `Produkt`, `Produktversion`, `Menge`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Looking in `phpmyadmin`; I created new entrys, but only `id` and `Datum` are filled values, the others are empty. 'id' and 'Datum' are automatically set because of `identifier` and `currenttimestamp` for those.

Whats wrong with $value1 - $value4?

Comment: Its wrong that you got `name"Kunde"` you are missing **equal sign** **=** `name="Kunde"` same on all other names and in `value"Insert"` need to be `value="Insert"` in yours html form. And if "id" is set to auto increment you don't need to insert it, this is done automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `index.php` as below:

```
<form action="index3.php" method="POST">

    Kunde: <input type="text" name="Kunde">
    <br/>
    Produkt: <input type="text" name="Produkt">
    <br/>
    Produktversion: <input type="text" name="Produktversion">
    <br/>
    Menge: <input type="text" name="Menge">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert">

</form>
```